# How to get an output in a certain way in R

Tags: r, output

This is a simple program in R

```
a<-5
sink("output.txt")
for (i in seq(1,5)) {
a=a+1
print(a)
}

b<-1
for (i in seq(1,5)) {
b=b+1
print(b)
}
sink()
```

The output that I am getting in a text file is -

```
> for (i in seq(1,5)) {
+   a=a+1
+   print(a)
+ }
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10

> b<-1

> for (i in seq(1,5)) {
+   b=b+1
+   print(b)
+ }
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6

> sink()
```

However, I just want the output in text of this form -

```
 6  2
 7  3
 8  4
 9  5
 10 6
```

How can I get this? I tried `\n` putting in the program at many places but always got an error.

Comment: use `cat()` with a `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a single `for` loop and `print` both 'a' and 'b' by concatenating the output in each run

```
a <- 5
b <- 1
for(i in seq(1, 5)) {
  a <- a+ 1
  b <- b + 1
  cat(c(a, b), '\n')
}
# 6 2 
# 7 3 
# 8 4 
# 9 5 
#10 6
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove `[1]` ? I have to run a very large loop(`seq(1,10000)`] and in the output I don't need this.

Comment: @Dark_Knight IN that case, replace the `print` with `cat`

Comment: @Dark_Knight  Sorry, I didn't quite get your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I made a wrong comment. I meant to say that is it also possible to remove the program that also comes written in the exported text file along with the main result?

Comment: @Dark_Knight  `remove the program` - Did you meant the codes when using `sink`?  In that case, use `capture.output` i.e. `capture.output(for(i in seq(1, 5)){....code...}, file  = "output.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do away with the `for` loop

```
cat(paste0(paste(a + seq(1,5), b + seq(1,5)), collapse="\n"))
```